# Scaffold-DbContext different namespace on context and models

Tags: entity-framework, namespaces, scaffold

I run command for get DBContext and Models from existing database

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Force -OutputDir "../Project.Domain/Models" -ContextDir "../Project.Data" -Connection "Server=.;Database=xxx;user id=zzz;password=yyy;" -Provider "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"
```

Now proble is that DBContext at Project.Data file does not have reference to Project.Domain/Models and I need add it by hand (SO generating code always break my code).. Is there way to get that "using Project.Domain.Models" automatically for DBContext file?